# How to run this code involving away3d with Adobe Flash CS6?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d, away3d, flash-cs6

I have recently downloaded Flash CS6 and wanted to set up a 3d engine with it.

I downloaded Away3d but now I am having troubles setting it up because I a newb.

This here is the code that I want to run -  taken from this website - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/creating-games-away3d.html

```
_view = new View3D();
_view.backgroundColor = 0x666666; 
_view.antiAlias = 4; 
this.addChild(_view); 
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
```

I have added the away3d src folder in Adobe Flash CS6.
But when I run this code, I see a blank screen.

I think I am forgetting how to import it or may be put it in a class or something.
Can somebody explain that procedure?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your Flash CS6 publish settings? As in, source path, library path,  player version, etc. Are you getting any compiler warnings or runtime errors (in the "Output" window)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok:

Download away3d gold or alpha:
setup a folder like the image below.

[image]
open and go to the bin folder you will find the "away3d.swc" File copy this file to the folder SWC_libs.

make all your files look the same as the picture, its just easier.
Creat a project named"My_PROJECT". now go to the advance actionScript Settings:[image]

in the library Path click the add button or browse option now select the path where you put that swc file before...//My_3d_Projects/SWC_libs/away3d.swc: